# TextFields are at the incorrect locations when using Push instead of Modal

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, segue

I have a simple table view controller which has a plus button in the navigation bar. That modally leads to a place where users can insert information into text fields. These are situated throughout the view controller.

When it comes to editing a cell from the table view, I use a "Push" segue instead of modal because that seems more natural for the user experience rather than a view controller coming up. I have created a new view controller for the "editing" with the same text fields in the same location.

When I use the push segue, all of the text fields are a long way below where they should be. I've checked the x,y position and it's exactly the same as the modal view to add.

When I use Modal, then everything is exactly where it should be.

My table view is embedded inside a navigation controller so I thought when I push to another view, it would just accept that in the navigation controller.

Please could anyone shed some light on this as to why with a push segue, I'm getting messed up views, and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using auto layout to position your views?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that - Auto-Layout is being used on both the add and edit view controller

Comment: Then something is wrong with your constraints. What constraints do you have on the labels in the controller you're pushing to?

Comment: I will have a look, but to be honest, I just left the auto layout as default - created the same way I did the Add Entry

Comment: You should add the ones you want, rather than leaving it up to the system.

Comment: Does the y-offset happen to be the height of your navigation bar?

Comment: Hi Mischa - sorry, how would I check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing the push is your controller using the whole height of the screen or not?

Could be the navigation bar and status bar are causing them to be out of place where as in the modal you would only have the status bar if not hidden

Comment: That's very interesting - thanks Darren for the reply. I'm not using full screens and on my modal view, I have a navigation bar because there are some bar button items, etc.. I've put the navigation bar also on this push view.. and also removed it (using the bar from the navigation controller) but am getting the same results both times

Comment: understood, just thought it might be the issue due to the new full screen behavior with iOS7

Comment: Thanks Darren - great point though - I'm going to work with it for a bit and perhaps create it again to see if that solves it - weird!